# Dynamically add a class to a module in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I create a module dynamically like so:

```
app = Object.const_set('CoolModule', Module.new)
```

Is there anyway to add a class to that module? Something like this maybe?

```
app << (class Application; end)
```

I'm basically trying to get the following going

```
module 'CoolModule'.turnThisIntoAModule
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.blabla = 2
  end
end
```

Comment: Not clear how the first code is relevant. Can't you start with `CoolModule` given?

Comment: More context  as to why will help us answer how.

Comment: Your title includes the word, "dynamically", but you do not say, in the statement of your question, that you want to create the class dynamically.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Because "dynamically" is modifying the verb phrase "add a class", not the nonexistent phrase "create a class". He wants to add a static class to a dynamically-specified module.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, how can you "dynamically add a class" statically? Also, there is no such thing as a "static class".  Let's see what Ingo says.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I didn't say "dynamically add a class statically". I said "dynamically add a static class". And by "static class" I meant "a class whose content is always the same"; i.e. the opposite of dynamic.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, you have to freeze a class to prevent it from being changed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I did not say a class whose content cannot be changed. I said a class whose content is the same, with an implied "at the time of insertion". Please stop being pedantic. It's just annoying.

Comment: I'm not being pedantic. I just don't like members using inane terms like "static class" when no one here knows what they mean.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That I understand. However, forcing me to repeat a specific phrase in my original comment, then clarify that with a detail that was originally implied, is pedantic. As is your original comment, in addition to being based on an incorrect interpretation.

Comment: To clarify a bit, I want to to create a module, where the name of the module comes from a string  (so creating a module, dynamically). Then I want to add a well defined class (not created on the fly, can call it static or not, I don't really mind) to that module, and later be able to call CoolModule::Application and get the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add a class for dynamically named module like in the following example:

```
app = Object.const_set('CoolModule', Module.new)

Object.const_get('CoolModule').
  const_set('Application', Class.new(Rails::Application) do
    config.blabla = 2
  end)
```

If you have access to `app` object at point of call, it may replace `Object.const_get('CoolModule')` expression, of course.

`Module.module_eval` suggests itself but it unfortunately does not do scoped lookup in its block form. It does it in the string argument form, but I'd discourage use of evals on strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot lad, ive been searching for this feature so long. One question: Is it a bad way to work with Object object straight?

Answer (score 2):

You just repeat the same thing.

```
CoolModule.const_set("SomeVeryDynamicName", Module.new do
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.blabla = 2
  end
end)
```

Comment: Good answer to a pretty ambiguous question. However, here we are adding a module to a module where the inner module is created dynamically (which is correct if we base the answer on the name of the question). Ultimately, I want to be able to call CoolModule::Application and get the class.